# If the random variable X is "absolutely continuous," then it is integrable. (Or is it?)

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, random-variables

In *Probability Theory* (Williams), there is a lemma stating the following "absolute continuity" property of random variables:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ be a probability space, and let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable.

If $X \in \mathcal{L}^1 := \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that whenever $F \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(F) < \delta$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[|X| 1_{F}]< \epsilon$.

My question: **Is the converse true, as well?**

That is: If, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that whenever $F \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(F) < \delta$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[|X| 1_{F}]< \epsilon$, is it then true that $X \in \mathcal{L}^1$?

My thought was that this should certainly be the case, but I'm having some trouble actually proving it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true.

We can argue like this. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Now since $\mathbb{P}(|X| > K) \rightarrow 0$ for $K\rightarrow \infty$, we can choose a $K$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|X| > K) < \delta$, where $\delta$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}(F)< \delta \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[|X|1_F] < \epsilon$.

We can now compute
$$\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \mathbb{E}[|X| 1_{\{|X|\leq K\}} ] + \mathbb{E}[|X| 1_{\{|X|> K\}}] \leq K+\epsilon < \infty $$
and conclude that $X\in \mathcal{L}^1$.

Comment: So, this was actually the approach I had in mind; but I couldn't figure out how to justify that $P(|X| > K) \to 0$ as $K \to \infty$. After all, $|X|$ may not be bounded (if it were, we'd be done); and so it could be that, e.g., for some $\alpha > 0$, $P(|X| > K) \ge \alpha$ for all $K$ (i.e., $P(|X| > K)$ is uniformly bounded from below by some positive number $\alpha$). Of course, we do have Markov's Inequality: $P(|X| \ge K) \le \mathbb{E}[|X|]/K$; but, again, if the expectation isn't finite, this is of no use either...

Comment: Recall that in general we have for $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 ...$, that
$$\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n)$$
Now since 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{ |X| > n \} = \emptyset $$
we have that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X| > n) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0$$

Comment: Hmm. I believe you, but I'm having trouble convincing myself that $\cap_n \{|X| > n\} = \emptyset$. Consider the following argument: Suppose $|X|$ is not bounded (which is, of course, what we're worried about). Then, for each $n$, we can find an $\omega_n \in \Omega$ such that $|X(\omega_n)| > n$. Now, since this $\omega_n$ depends on our choice of $n$, we haven't necessarily shown that $\cap_n \{|X| > n\}$ is nonempty; but how do we know that, e.g., the sequence $(\omega_n)$ doesn't converge to some $\omega \in \Omega$ (that would then be an element of $\cap_n \{|X| > n\}$)?

Comment: Suppose that it is non-empty and let $\omega \in \cap_n \{|X| > n\}$. By definition this would mean that $|X(\omega)| > n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but how can a real number be greater than all natural numbers?

Comment: Ok. I guess I'm just having an issue with the quantifiers a bit here. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Note that $\mathbb{P}(|X| > k) = 1-F_{|X|}(k)$ where $F_{|X|}$ is the CDF, so these arguments actually also shows why CDF's always converge to $1$.